# Однотипные данные?

Tags: javascript

Читал тему про массивы(javascript), там сказано, что в массивах желательно использовать

однотипные упорядоченные данные.

Что такое **однотипные упорядоченные данные?**

Функция относится к однотипным упорядоченным данным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот совет относится к разработке програм, где производительность работы с массивами имеет критическое значение. Он связан с внутренними особенностями движков JavaScript, в частности V8, на котором исполняется JavaScript в Chrome и Node.js.

Если кратко: под упорядоченностью подразумевается отсутствие дыр в массивах, а под однотипностью — отсутствие разных типов данных в массиве.

Если вы добавляете элементы в массив не подряд (например, добавили элемент по индексу 0, а потом по индексу 10), между ними образуется дыра (на месте элементов по индексам от 1 до 9), что мешает оптимизации работы с массивами.

Также движок различает некоторые типы данных в качестве элементов массивов: малые целые числа, дробные числа, остальные данные (например, строки). Если вы создали массив с малыми целыми, он будет оптимизирован под этот тип. Если вы добавите туда дробные, оптимизация будет снижена. Добавите строки — будет снижена ещё раз.

Если захотите почитать подробнее и читаете на английском, вот пост от разработчиков V8: https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, более всего оптимизированы массивы с малыми целыми, потом с дробными, потом с остальными данными, потом идут массивы с дырами. Так что, наверное, правило скорее звучит так: не стоит добавлять в массивы с большей оптимизацией элементы из массивов с меньшей. Поскольку массивы с функциями не самые оптимизированные, вы вряд ли испортите их, если добавите туда число. А вот добавлением функции в массив с числами вы оптимизацию понизите. Но, как вам сказали выше, на этот стоит обращать внимание, только если вы увидите критическое падение скорости в работе с массивами.

Comment: Если железо(СPU,GPU,RAM) мощное, то падение скорости не так сильно будет заметно)?

Comment: Я не спец в этой сфере, поэтому точно сказать не могу. Всё зависит от специфики программ, которые вы разрабатываете. Если они  постоянно обрабатывают много больших массивов с числами (например, работают с графикой или математическими вычислениями), но разница может быть заметна. Если они время от времени перебирают небольшие массивы, то разница может быть меньше. Как и с любой производительностью, нужно замерять и искать «бутылочное горлышко», и только потом уже его оптимизировать, иначе вы можете впустую тратить время на незначительные вещи.